# How to add specific page as ajax loading screen to website?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, loading

I want to add a PHP page with custom ajax loading design as ajax loader to website pages.  I'm currently using very simple code in below and I need your help to guide me how to add my PHP page in this loading screen code.

Here is JavaScript code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    var load_screen = document.getElementById("load_screen");
    document.body.removeChild(load_screen);
});
```

and

```
<div id="load_screen"> <div id="loading">loading document </div></div>
```

The above code currently is working well, but it's only text, I need to show `ajax.php` instead of that loading screen text.

actually I did like this, but both pages load together, I mean `ajax.php` and main page will load together, it should be `ajax.php` first then after main page will load, but I don't know why both of them load together, what is the wrong with my code?

```
<div id="load_screen"> <div id="loading"><?php include "ajax.php"; ?></div></div>
```

> **1:** How can I add **ajax.php** instead of **loading document** text ?
>
> **2:** How to add timer for this loading?
>
> **3:** Why ajax.php and main page (both) load together? It should be ajax.php load first then main page will load. so how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: What is the contents of ajax.php?

Comment: ajax.php is a perfect page including design , texts, css, js, css fonts, images, div, span, it's full page design for ajax loading design,

Comment: OK. Maybe the browser is having a difficult time if there are multiple `<html>` tags in the same document? How long does the page take to load?

Comment: _ajax.php is a perfect page including design , texts, css.._ You have chosen wrong way. AJAX is only to load _**data**_ to be processed by JS/DOM means (e.g. JSON or html text to be inserted by DOM methods). AJAX is not intended to load/display a full page with linked resources. The only way to do so is use [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).

Comment: iframe isnt good way for this ajax loader, I need a best solution for this

Comment: ---if a loading page got css ,, text ,, fonts ,, imgs,, it will already take lots of time to load .. the idea in a loading page is that it's a light weight content that loads fast (most commonly css only or gif) ,, that loads and shows then we hide it ...

Comment: Ok thank you for your help and information.